# Zend Framework Curl - debug GET

Tags: php, curl, zend-framework

How do I view the actual raw GET request?

```
    $config = array(
        'adapter'   => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
        'curloptions' => array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true),
    );

    $client = new Client($this->uri, $config);

    $client->setParameterGet(array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ));        

    $response = $client->send($client->getRequest());

    echo htmlentities($response->getBody()."<br/>"); // The response is as expected. But I need to see the RAW request so I can debug.
    die();
```

Comment: I needed to make sure that `$client->setParameterGet()` was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
'curloptions' => array(
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => fopen('/tmp/curl.txt', 'a+'),
),
```

`CURLOPT_VERBOSE` enables verbose output to `CURLOPT_STDERR`, which we specify above as a file.

Typically, you can also use `fopen('php://output', 'w')` to see debug output on the same stream `echo` or `print` use.

See [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) and [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) for more info.